# jQuery Listen For All Text Input Changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, events

I have an input element within a form which I would like to be able to extract its value when the value changes. Take a look at this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/spryno724/WaBzW/1/.

By using the `change` event, I am able to display the value from the text input when the input looses focus. However, the value does not update when the form is reset or when JavaScript clears the value of the text input.

Is there a specific event that I can listen for which will be dispatched when ***any*** change is made to a text input control?

**I'd like to avoid work-arounds, such as listening for when the form is reset, or when the clear button is pressed**. This is a simplified example of what my application does, and it will get crazy pretty fast if I try to do all of that.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I was just working on this same problem today. The jQuery `.on` event is supposed to handle this but I couldn't make it work. `$("#ElementID").on("input change propertychange paste keyup", handler)`...

Comment: Hmm... I've never used `.on()` before. I'll look into it

Comment: I've used `.live()` before but that has been deprecated as of version 1.7 and `.on()` is now the preferred method

Comment: @AlfalfaStrange see my comment to Johnny on the `.live()` event

Comment: @thecodeparadox Thanks for bolding the important notes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JS Events: hooking on value change event on text inputs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847893/js-events-hooking-on-value-change-event-on-text-inputs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is an exact duplicate of another. See the answer with the highest number of up-votes as the answer to my question:

[JS Events: hooking on value change event on text inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847893/js-events-hooking-on-value-change-event-on-text-inputs)

Comment: You're meant to (vote to) close the question as a duplicate then, not post an answer.

Answer (score 13):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input.clear').click(function() {
        $('input.input').val('');
        $('p.display').text('The value of the text input is: ');
    });

    $('input.input').on('keyup change', function() {
       $('p.display').text('The value of the text input is: ' + $(this).val());
    });
})​
```

**[DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/3tDFg/1/)**

Probably this solution may help you:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input.clear, input[type=reset]').on('click', function() {
        $('input.input').val('').change();
        $('p.display').text('The value of the text input is: ');
    });

    $('input.input').on('keyup change', function() {
        $('p.display').text('The value of the text input is: ' + $(this).val());
    });
});​
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/3tDFg/3/)**

Comment: Thank you, but hitting reset will not update the text above the input.

Comment: What about when data is set to the value of the input from another function? `.keyup` won't cover that

Comment: I appreciate your input, but I had also mentioned that I would "like to avoid work-arounds, such as listening for when the form is reset, or when the clear button is pressed. This is a simplified example of what my application does, and it will get crazy pretty fast if I try to do all of that."

Comment: I see. It does work. However, resetting the form doesn't update the text above the input.

Comment: @spryno724 Reset doesn't work but clear does.. what is reset supposed to do?

Comment: Reset is an HTML feature which will clear (or reset) all of the form elements within a given form to their default values.

Comment: Using the selector `$('form').on('keyup change', 'input.input', function() {});` will be much faster when you have a lot of fields. http://jsfiddle.net/duqt8jv2/

Answer (score 1):

Override `val` method of jQuery

**HTML**

`<input id='myInput' name='myInputField' value='v1'>`

**JS**

```
var myInput = $('#myInput');

//this will not trigger the change event
myInput.val('v2');

//override val method
var oldVal = myInput.val;
myInput.val = function(value){
   var returnVal = oldVal.call(this,value);
   myInput.change();
   return returnVal;
}

// this will trigger the change event
// myInput.val is overridden
myInput.val('v3');
```

> **NOTE**  this will work only if val method is called from `myInput` variable

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
$('#input').live('change',function() {         })
```

Comment: `.live()` is whenever there are new elements which are dynamically added to the page and must have events attached to them: http://api.jquery.com/live/.

Comment: Do NOT use `.live()` it has been deprecated as of version 1.7

Comment: I know what you've said is true about it being deprecated.  Strangely I had a situation where I wanted to change the background color of an input when it's value changed, and using .live('change'... worked while using .on('change'... didn't work - using jquery 1.7.3.  Any idea why?

Comment: Yeah I have had the same problem, I think I just suck at jQuery

Comment: @JohnnyMnemonic you need to pass in the selector context to `on`, otherwise it will just work as if you are using `.change()` `.on( events [, selector] [, data], handler(eventObject) )`

Comment: @JohnnyMnemonic Please update your answer to reflect the changes to the API. As it currently stands, it doesn't solve OPs problem and it will likely only promote bad practice.