# Listen on programatically html input changes

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I want to listen on changes done in a html input field. The changes aren't done by a user but a script sets the value (onchange won't work thus). Unfortunately I have no access to the script/code.

The browser is IE 7 or 8. I don't know exactly as the page isn't shown in a real browser but in an application that uses the IE engine to display my html pages.

The application is a kind of state machine that is programmed via a GUI and not text code. I can let it show any page I want and I can also link internal variables with input fields/DOM elements in the html page. The application loads the page as is and after loading is done (and the onload method in body is executed) it will fill the linked elements with the contents of the variables.

The graphical programming is a real mess and I want to do as much work in the HTML pages with Javascript but I haven't found a way to add my scripts so that the internal variables are filled before it is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are IE-only, like you mentioned IE 7 and 8, try onpropertychange.  From another posting: [JS Events: hooking on value change event on text inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847893/js-events-hooking-on-value-change-event-on-text-inputs)

Comment: Even if the application is targeted to IE users using IE-only things is a really bad idea...

Comment: ThiefMaster:  ?  I'm sorry, but it's also bad idea to limit yourself to the cross-browser set of options when you know that something is *only* going to be run in some particular browser.  For instance:  If I had to do something inside a browser instance inside an application for an iOS device, I wouldn't even consider properties for IE or Firefox.  This sounds similar, but in a reverse fashion.  I doubt was never meant to be cross browser.  Of course, doing so does limit one's future options, but frankly, the design of this application sounds like a mess to begin with.