# Track of changes in an HTML form inside of a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a modal dialog in my App that contains about 10 inputs (i.e. text, dates, number and select inputs). I need know if value of any of the widget changed by the user, so that when they click on the cancel button I can prompt them if they like to save changes before closing the dialogue window.

I can do this in two ways, which may not be the smartest way:

1) set a global variable in my javaScript and keep track in "onChange" event.

2) Compare the value of each widget or inputs before and after to determine if any of them changed.

I wonder if there are any other options that I am not aware of since I am new to jQuery and javaScript.

I apologize if this a duplicate question, I searched and found another similar issue but not what I am after. 
[Best way to track onchange as-you-type in input type="text"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574941/best-way-to-track-onchange-as-you-type-in-input-type-text)

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this has an answer for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311663/find-out-if-html-form-has-changed

Comment: @MichaelPlotke he's covered that in his question.

Comment: @Michael_Plotke thanks for your response. SomeKittens_Ux2666 answered my question below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dirty flag:

```
var dirty = false;
$('#myModalForm input').change(function() {
  dirty = true;
});
$('#myModalForm #cancelButton').click(function() {
  if (dirty) {
    //confirm
  }
  // exit modal
});
$('#myModalForm #save').click(function() {
  // save
  dirty = false;
});
```

Comment: @SomeKittens_Ux2666 thanks for your example. This is much better than what I was doing. It worked for all form fields except "Select/Option" fields. So I just added following: $('#myModalForm select').change(function() {
  dirty = true;
});

Comment: //
One more thing to add is when user is not saving then set the variable to false so that user can open the dialogue again
if (dirty) {
    //confirm
    if (confirm("Do not save?"))
 dirty = false;
  }
  // exit modal